# CH341A Voltages for an AT45DB041B

Tags: flash

First off - I'm fairly new to electronics

I've been probing an AT45DB041B on a mobile printer board using my CH341A

The voltages on the printer board for the AT45DB041B pins are 3v

I just discovered that the CH341A is outputting 5v (Supposedly there's a fix for this)

Is there a chance I might have damaged the AT45DB041B or other components on the printer board?

Cheers

Edit: Not this exact model but some other knockoff (probably)
https://www.amazon.ca/Programmer-CH341A-Burner-EEPROM-Writer/dp/B01D4CXYJE

Edit2: I was using it to try to red data from MOSI/MISO. The CH341A outputs 5v on VCC/MISO/MOSI instead of 3v

Comment: Thanks for the feedback j.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CH341](http://www.wch-ic.com/products/CH341.html) is the name of the Jiangsu Haoheng USB-Serial interface chip used on the board. It is not very useful in describing the board.

The [AT45DB041B](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/doc3443.pdf) is an SPI flash memory, 3.6V maximum.

Yes, it's possible to damage the memory chip or the MCU connected to it if the voltages are wrong. It's also possible to cause damage by probes slipping and shorting, ESD etc. If it still works completely it's unlikely you damaged it much.